# How to split from file that has dynamic entries

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, split

I am trying to split a lot of strings that read from file line by line
 
Here is the some of the content inside the file :

```
Jack, 50, Aldwynne, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
Goe, 23, Clearden, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
Mike, 33, Marblesilver, Field1, Field2
Lupis, 38, Aldfair, Field1, Field2, Field3
Frey, 21, Verttown, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
Zulian, 45, Fogedge, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
```

My Code :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME))
String currLine;
while ((currLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String []arr = currLine.trim().split("\\s*,[,\\s]*");

String first=arr[0];
String second=arr[1];
String third=arr[2];
String fourth=arr[3];
String fifth=arr[4];
String sixth=arr[5];
String seventh=arr[6];
String eighth=arr[7];

// Next Process
}
```

Then i store each of them to the variables. The first two lines are fine, but the problem is the third line will generate Error `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` because it has no 4th index in it. Therefore, the program stop at 3rd line

So how to set empty string (`""`) to the missing index from the line which has length below 8. What i want is like below (ex : line #3 )

```
String first="Mike";
String second="33";
String third="Marblesilver";
String fourth="Field1";
String fifth="Field2";
String sixth="";
String seventh="";
String eighth="";
```

and so on. How do i do that ?

Comment: check the arr length and assign empty string if less than expected

Comment: just use n as counter and check if n>= arr.length. For these fields set empty String. Like String sixth=(n>=arr.length)?"":arr[n++];

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complete the other fields with an empty String, If you are using Java 8 you can read your file like so :

```
String fileName = "file.txt";
String regex = "\\s*,[,\\s]*";
int maxLength = 8;//This should be know from the beginning 
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    stream.map(line -> {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(line.split(regex)));
        List<String> emptyFields = IntStream.range(0, maxLength - list.size())
                .mapToObj(s -> "")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.addAll(list.size(), emptyFields);
        return list;
    }).forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In your case It will show you :

```
[Jack, 50, Aldwynne, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5]
[Goe, 23, Clearden, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5]
[Mike, 33, Marblesilver, Field1, Field2, , , ]           //note the empty fields in the end
[Lupis, 38, Aldfair, Field1, Field2, Field3, , ]
[Frey, 21, Verttown, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5]
[Zulian, 45, Fogedge, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5]
```

---

Beside I would create a class of MyObject which hold this information instead of an Array, so your code should look like :

```
public class MyObject {

    private String first;
    private String second;
    private String third;
    private String fourth;
    private String fifth;
    private String sixth;
    private String seventh;
    private String eighth;

    //...Constructor, Getters, Setter
}
```

---

```
...
List<MyObject> result = stream.map(line -> {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(line.split(regex)));
    List<String> emptyFields = IntStream.range(0, maxLength - list.size())
            .mapToObj(s -> "")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.addAll(list.size(), emptyFields);
    return list;
}).map(line -> new MyObject(line.get(0),
        line.get(1), line.get(2), line.get(3), line.get(4),
        line.get(4), line.get(5), line.get(6))
).collect(Collectors.toList());
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and suggestion, i tried and it worked , and it confused me :[ , I am new in Java , so i need to get used with it
btw , does your solution has less complexity than @m4gic 's??

Comment: You can test it @HenryLietzberg I can't judge the other solution, You can create a benchmark and check which one is faster :)

Answer (score 1):

for example, you can do this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
String currLine;
while ((currLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String []readed = currLine.trim().split("\\s*,[,\\s]*");
    String []arr = new String [8];
    Arrays.fill(arr, "");
    System.arraycopy(readed, 0, arr, 0, readed.length);
    ...
    // Next Process
}
// do not forget to close it, in finally block or by using try-with-resources statement
br.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works , actually i've tried declare at begin new array with empty string as its content , then i realized this `split` function make the array's length fewer . I never thought, I could just copy the result of `split` into new array
Once again Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use another Array, to not store as per field. Something like in my below example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String [] arr={"Jack", "50", "Aldwynne", "Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4", "Field5"};
    String []resultArray = new String[1024]; // Any max lenght you want

    for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++)
        resultArray[i] = arr[i];
    for(int j = arr.length; j < resultArray.length; j++)
        resultArray[j] = "";
}
```

Using resultArray, you will not get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, as long as the Max length of the array is more or equal to the required number of values.